# How can I make a volume slider in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I was wondering how to make a simple volume slider in XNA. Need one to adjust volume in a game I'm making, it's my first game in c#.

I've looked around and can't find a simple method to make a slider.

Anyone know an easy way that someone new to c# (but not to coding) could make one?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using the `MasterVolume` property of `SoundEffect`. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.mastervolume.aspx))

`MasterVolume` affects the volume of *all* your sounds, to adjust the volume of a specific sound effect, you'd use `SoundEffectInstance.Volume` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.volume.aspx))

Both of the properties go from `0.0f` (silence) to `1.0f` (maximum volume).

Basically, all there should be to it is drawing your slider, drawing the handle on that slider at the slider's x (assuming origin at top-left), plus the slider's width times the current master volume, and then adding in some way of controlling the slider, be it with the keyboard, or by clicking/dragging.

Clicking at it should just be waiting for a click, checking whether or not it's inside the slider's rectangle, and if it is, take the x minus the slider's x (again assuming origin at top-left), and divide that value by the slider's width, and that should be your new `MasterVolume`.

Comment: Can you explain how to test if you're moving the slider with the mouse e.g

    if (slider.isClicked) {
        // Some logic for testing if the mouse has moved left or right
        // Some logic for moving the sliders X position
       soundEffectInstance.Volume = slider.X / 100;
    }

Comment: What part is it you need help with, the slider.isClicked, or what?

Comment: The logic to check where your mouse is moving (left or right) and moving the X of the slider depending on how the mouse is moved

Comment: You don't need to check where the mouse is moving, just where it is, which you can get via a `MouseState` object, which you can get with `Mouse.GetState()`. The slider goes from `(x, y)`, the top left corner, to `(x + width, y + height)`, the bottom right corner. But we're only interested in values between `0` and `width`, so we take the mouse x (if the mouse is on the slider), subtract the slider x, and we'll get a value between `0` and the slider's `width`. We then divide that value by the slider `width` to get a value between `0.0f`, and `1.0f`, which is what we assign to our master volume.